# SELECT DNAME FROM DEPT WHERE DNAME LIKE 'S%' AND LOC LIKE '%S';

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DNAME 
FROM DEPT 
WHERE DNAME LIKE 'S%' AND LOC LIKE '%S';
```

When I execute the above query I get the following result.

```
SQL> SELECT DNAME FROM DEPT WHERE DNAME LIKE 'A%' AND LOC LIKE '%E';
```

no rows selected

My table is:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM DEPT;

   DEPTNO DNAME           LOC
---------- --------------- --------
        10 ACCOUNTING      NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH        DALLAS
        40 INVENTORY       HYBD
        50 FINANCE         BGLR
        30 HR              MUMBAI
```

Why is it not showing the Accounting and Finance departments

Comment: Can you re-title your question?

Comment: There is no row that matches the condition "dname starts with A **and** location ends with E". The only row that matches  `DNAME LIKE 'A%'` has a `LOC` that ends with `'K'`

Comment: what exaclty you want ?

Answer (score 1):

Because the record

```
10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
```

has not a **LOC** ending with **E**

and the record

```
50 FINANCE         BGLR
```

has not **LOC** ending with **E** and also **DNAME** starting with **A**

Answer (score 0):

Its showing *no rows selected*   because there is LOC ending with E.`('%E')`

More About SQL [Pattern Matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Why are you linking to the MySQL manual when the Thirumal is clearly using Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result "Accounting" and "Finance". Try this code below

```
SELECT DNAME 
FROM DEPT 
WHERE DNAME LIKE 'A%' OR DNAME LIKE '%E';
```